# Grouping by key with Apache Spark but want to apply contcat between values instead of using an aggregate function

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm learning Spark and want to perform the following task: I want to use `group by` but the grouping condition shown below is different and not well known in Spark, any help will be appreciated.

I've an `RDD[String,String]` with data ->

```
8 kshitij

8 vini

8 mohan

8 guru

5 aashish

5 aakash

5 ram
```

I want to convert it to an `RDD[String,Set[String]]` ->

```
8 Set[kshitij, vini, mohan, guru]

5 Set[aashish, aakash, ram]
```

Comment: Why not just `rdd.groupByKey()`?

Answer (score 2):

As user52045 said in the comments, you can just use `groupByKey`, which results in a `RDD[String, Iterable[String]]`. This is part of the `RDDPairFunctions` available through implicit conversions for any `Tuple2`.

The only open question is whether you're ok with an `Iterable`, or if it has to be a `Set`, which would require an additional step of calling mapValues, or some customization through `aggregateByKey` (if you want it in one go)

Comment: "would require some customization through aggregateByKey" Or just run `.mapValues(_.toSet)` on the result?